# Closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n \choose k}a^{k^2}}$

Tags: summation, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

I think the following sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n \choose k}a^{k^2}}$$

could be computed recursively using the fact that $(k+1)^2 = k^2+2k+1$, but do somebody know some reference work about that problem, or maybe even its generalization for any positive integer $m$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n \choose k}a^{k^m}}$$

Comment: I doubt that the sum above has a simple closed form.  However, you can replace $a^{k^m}$ by $e^{t k^m}$ and then Taylor-expand $e^{tk^m}$ as a series in the variable $t$.  Then the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} k^{mr}$ can be computed for any integers $m,r\ge0$.  It might yield some hypergeometric series, I don't know.